# Hitting npm error while running npm -version

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I need node10+ version for Angular 8 CLI and while using node10.16.2, I get the error shown below, and see the same error while running `npm build`

```
npm-v10.16.2 -v
/auto/sw/packages/node/v10.16.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:84
let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^
```

> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
>   at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
>   at startup (node.js:148:18)
>   at node.js:405:3

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your node package to solve this issue.

If you're on ubuntu, try running

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

This will install the latest node package.